# add "bookmarks" in Dreamweaver CS4?

Tags: dreamweaver, cs4

Does anyone know a way to "bookmark" a line of code, for easy reference later on?

It would be very helpful if i could mark a line of code maybe such as "need to fix this someday" or "XYZ variable set here", etc...

Currently i just scroll through code looking for comments or use the Find functionality but some of my projects have so many JS files included that it can become time consuming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this](http://forums.adobe.com/message/4504871) and other posts on the Adobe forums, there is no bookmark feature in Dreamweaver. Apparently it has been added to the requested feature list.